# How do I report on History field tracking with Custom Objects?

Tags: reporting

I want to track the fields History that getting changed. i want the report that provide the old value of any field and also new value of that field.
Lets i want to track the keyword custom field. if changed the keyword than it will show the new value and also its old value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The history reports provide this functionality - if you enable field tracking for a standard/custom object (e.g. Case) then when you create a report you can choose the type 'Case History'.  This will show who made the edit, when the edit was made, the name of the field and its old and new value.  The only caveats to this that I'm aware of are:

(1) You can only report on fields that you have turned on history tracking for

(2) large text area fields don't have the old/new values retained, so those appear as '-'.

(3) You can't report on the change history of custom objects that are the detail in a master-detail relationship.

Comment: We need to track long area text fields and obviously this is not possible in Salesforce.

The 255 character text fields are not long enough and we need to be able to report on whether the initial requirement has changed, therefore need a full history of the long text field.

Has anyone come across this problem and if so, do you have a solution?

Comment: My solution below would solve that problem.

Comment: Steve's solution is exactly what I've used in the past for customers with this requirement.  It does mean you need to apply changes twice - once to the real object and once to the shadow.  If you have a lot of churn on your records you can quickly consume a lot of data storage space also.

Answer (score 3):

I might be going out on a limb here, but I don't believe you can't use field history tracking in the way you described.

I would suggest keeping a 'shadow' custom object and use a before trigger to back up the fields to the shadow object.  Then you should be able to write a report that uses both objects/sets of fields.

If you report requirements are slightly more complex however, you may need to write a VF page to do the appropriate 'report' generation.

Comment: ya i already used field history tracking and than i made the report but it only gave true and false value in report old and new value section fields.

Comment: Were you tracking a boolean field?

Comment: This does look like an over kill

Comment: some fields don't have the old/new values retained,so those appear sometimes true or false. like check box.

Comment: -'true/false' would be 'checked/unchecked' 
-It's not overkill since the business requirements appear to be to track long text fields, something field history tracking doesn't do.

Comment: ya.. but   
We need to track long area text fields and obviously this is not possible in Salesforce. The 255 character text fields are not long enough and we need to be able to report on whether the initial requirement has changed, therefore need a full history of the long text field. Has anyone come across this problem and if so, do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Use New APp  Which is Native.

Very Helpful for the Mater Detail History tracking on Custom Object.  Which is not available.  Report can be exported in PDF and Excel Formate

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ex0LHUAZ